# Displaying the Boost matrix in form of line. Want to change it to Box

Tags: c++, boost

//This simple program initialize a 3x3 matrix and outputs it in the form of line.i want to display this matrix in the form of matrix.

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

int main(){
  using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
  matrix<double> m1(3,3);

 for(unsigned i=0;i<m1.size1();++i)
 for (unsigned j=0;j<m1.size2();++j)
     m(i,j)=3*i*j;
 std::cout<<m1<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
output
[3,3]((0,0,0),(0,3,6),(0,6,12)
```

Comment: My answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30364430/2640636

Comment: I can loops with cout to change in to BOX form...but i am looking something deep in the boost that will change it with least tying efforts

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
void printMatrix(const matrix<double> &m)
{
    for(unsigned i=0;i<m.size1();++i)
    {
        cout<<"| ";
        for (unsigned j=0;j<m.size2();++j)
        {
            cout<<m(i,j)<<" | ";
        }
        cout<<"|"<<endl;
    }
}
```

this will print something like this:

```
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 3 | 6 |
| 0 | 6 | 9 |
```

Comment: writing this much of code is something will not give bliss

Comment: thanks for the reply..but i could have do the same...but i am looking some thing elegant